# openCV mixing IplImage with cv::Mat

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, opencv, memory-leaks

I have experienced some memory managment ambiguitys with opencv. 
You could do this with the new opencv c++ classes:

```
cv::Mat theimage = cvLoadImage("rawimage.pgm",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);
```

now what I don t understand if I do the following I will get an error:

```
theimage.deallocate();
```

maybe this is wrong. I have made some experiments and when I release the Mat object:

```
theimage.release();
```

the IplImage object still remains in the memory. Is there some way to say to the cv::Mat object destroy the IplImage object or is my first line of code wrong (since there I have lost the pointer for the IplImage object) ?
I have seen a lot of exemples in the internet where people use the first line of code. Many explains how to convert but no one explains what happens with the memory !

Tthe problem is that I have many classes that are using the IplImage object (I started my project using that). And I understand why cv::Mat is better than IplImage.

--EDIT--

In the internet I have found following solution for the mixing:

```
cv::Ptr<IplImage> tmp = cvLoadImage("rawimage.pgm",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);
cv::Mat theimage(tmp);
```

I think this could solve some of my problems but makes my code a bit unreadable and is in my opinion stil dangerous. 
If tmp gets deallocated before cv::Mat I will use some corrupt objects (I didn t test that but I think it is so). The easy way would be to use a copy:

```
cv::Mat theimage(tmp,true);
```

this is the only solution that I found but for me it feels wrong...

Comment: The solution is to use `cv::imread()` instead of `cvLoadImage()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The ambiguity comes from an extremelly horrible practice**: mixing the C interface with the C++ interface of OpenCV. Don't do it, use `cv::imread()` instead.

The destructor of `cv::Mat` [will always deallocate memory when needed](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/intro.html#automatic-memory-management), **except** when it is [initialized from a `IplImage`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=deallocate#mat-operator-iplimage), then **it's up to you to free it's resources with `deallocate()`**. I wrote a simple experiment to verify this information:

```
void load()
{
    cv::Mat img = cvLoadImage("out.png", 1);

    std::cout << "* IMG was loaded\n";
    getchar();

    img.deallocate();
}

int main()
{
    load();

    std::cout << "* IMG was deallocated\n";
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

The `getchar()` calls pause the program so you can check the memory footprint of the application. If you comment out `deallocate()` you'll notice that the memory footprint doesn't decrease after loading the image.

On a side note, [`Mat::release()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=deallocate#mat-release) only decreases the reference counter and deallocates the data if needed (but it will also not deallocate in case the `Mat` was initialized from `IplImage`).

Comment: I dont think cv::Mat will deallocate memory when constructed from an IplImage. Its not safe after all.