# cv::Mat's release method

Tags: c++, opencv, free, mat

I would like to confirm whether `cv::Mat::release()` method is similar to `free()` in C programming, i.e., its deallocates the Matrix data from the memory.

In particular, I would like to understand the behaviour of this method with respect to memory leaks and make sure there is no leak in may programs.

Comment: Encapsulate your code inside a while(true){//loop} and let it run. In the meanwhile, monitor your memory with a task manager to reason about your memory.

Comment: There are specific tools to measure memory leaks and other programming mistakes (using uninitialized variables etc).  Take a look at «valgrind».

Answer (score 9):

If the reference counter is equal to one, then yes, `cv::Mat::release()` will decrement it to zero and deallocate the structure (like `free` in C).

If the reference counter is greater than one (ie. there's some other object interested in the structure), then `cv::Mat::release()` will *only* decrement the reference counter.

You can increment the reference counter of a `cv::Mat` structure (that is, to flag that you are interested in it and you don't want it to be deallocated) by invoking the `cv::Mat::addref()` method.

Comment: I have a cv::Mat v, and that is v.create() inside a loop  and the size of v is different for different iteration. then for the next iteration I like to remove the old one for creating the new one. Can i use release() or deallocate()?

Answer (score 6):

you don't have to manually deallocated cv::Mat objects since it is automatically managed , unless you have initialized the Mat from an Iplimage in this case you should manually deallocate it deallocate().

please refer to this thread .

[openCV mixing IplImage with cv::Mat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11156019/opencv-mixing-iplimage-with-cvmat)

Answer (score 6):

I was having memory leaks using a code structure like this (OpenCV with C++):

```
int i;
while(true){
    Mat x = imread("C:/pics"+i+".jpg");
    //do something with x
}
```

After 100 or so iterations it always crashed, then i changed the code to this:

```
int i;
while(true){
    Mat x = imread("C:/pics"+i+".jpg");
    //do something with x
    x.refcount = 0;
    x.release();
}
```

It stopped crashing and did the full iteration. But when setting the refcount manually to 0 you must be really sure that you dont need the object anymore.

Comment: Could you clarify the reason for your down-vote? Is it because youre missing my point?

Answer (score 0):

The following program snippet tests the behavior of Mat::release()
(adapted from [opencv-org-answer](http://answers.opencv.org/question/14285/how-to-free-memory-through-cvmat/))

```
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    cout << "test_mat_release.cpp" << endl;

    {
        //memory is released
        const char *pzInputImg = "data/em_sample.png";

        Mat img;
        img = imread(pzInputImg);
        assert(img.data);
        img.release();
        assert(!img.data);
    }
    {
        //memory is released
        Mat img(100, 100, CV_32FC1);
        assert(img.data);
        img.release();
        assert(!img.data);
    }

    {   
        //Since Mat does not owns data , data is not released
        //you have to explicitly release data
        int cols=17;
        int rows=15;
        unsigned char * data = new unsigned char[rows*cols*3];
        Mat img(rows, cols, CV_8UC3, data);
        assert(img.data);
        img.release();
        assert(!img.data);
        delete [] data;
    }



    Mat imgRef;
    {
        //memory is not released
        //since there img.data is now shared with imgRef
        Mat img(100, 100, CV_32FC1);
        imgRef=img;
        assert(img.data);
        assert(img.data == imgRef.data);
        img.release();
        assert(img.empty());
        assert(!img.data);
        //img.data is NULL, but imgRef.data is not NULL, so data is not de-allocated
        assert(!imgRef.empty());
        assert(imgRef.data);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: would be super great if in the last example you show a way to release memory, I suppose by releasing imgRef and then img...?

Comment: What is the reference is to a crop? like `Mat imgRef = img(roi);` what happens if I then release `img` and then try to also release imgRef?